# (QGIS) Creating a rule to hide labels based on their appearance on a list or array

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, fields-attributes, rule-based

I'm creating maps for a project, and I'm handling sensitive data. I have a list of species I can't display on maps. I would like to create a rule that checks if the value in column "species_name" matches with any of the restricted species in the list, and if it doesn't, the rule will draw a label and/or symbol for the value. If it does match, it shouldn't draw a symbol or label the point. So far, what I've tried fails to return any values, even for the entries that should be listed.

The data I'm trying to label looks like this, heavily simplified:

| Species_name | taxon |
| --- | --- |
| Bucephala clangula | bird |
| Buteo buteo | bird |

Bucephala clangula isn't on the restricted list, Buteo buteo is. For Buteo buteo, I can't show anything on the map.

I used (again, simplified):

```
CASE WHEN regexp_match("species_name",'buteo buteo|haliaeetus albicilla') THEN '' ELSE "species_name" END
```

Now it works, but I fear it is case sensitive, and I don't trust all the data I'm using to be identical. Is there a way to write it so that it isn't case sensitive? And is there a way to simplify the code so I wouldn't have to write all the species on the list, and could just use a variable that contains all the species on the restricted list? –

Comment: Please provide the expression you tried so far. Mock up data would be helpful, too.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to provide clarifications. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine comments for critical information

Comment: You may create an array containing all restricted species and compare your Species_name field against it using array_contain.

Comment: Also why not filtering the whole layer to remove record of restricted specie ? (a simple "species_name" NOT IN ('buteo buteo', 'haliaeetus albicilla', …, …) will do)

Comment: Filtering the whole layer is an option, but I also wanted to use this problem as a learning opportunity with qgis. Also, I don't want to remove the records of the sensitive species, because I need to use them myself for some assessments, I just want to hide them from the map. About your solution of comparing species_name against an array of restricted species names, how would you type the code in python? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not python but adapting your expression give this : CASE WHEN array_contains(array('buteo buteo', 'haliaeetus albicilla'),"species_name" ) THEN '' ELSE "species_name" END

Comment: I would go one step further, and split the dataset (if possible) to 'sensitive' and 'public' parts, for example saving the 2 parts to 2 GeoPackage files. It would lessen the need for filtering and expressions, and would give some protection against accidentally publishing sensitive data.

Comment: An intermediate solution to @crafter6029 proposition would be to duplicate your layer and use two opposite filter to get one layer of public species and a second layer of restricted species (you may use map theme to prevent accidentally showing the restricted layer in your layout)

Comment: Ideally, instead of filtering by hardcoded species, you would have a column in your data that indicates whether the species is sensitive or otherwise. If you have a separate list of sensitive species (like a CSV loaded into the project), you can use a lookup expression like `attribute(get_feature(..` (search the site for numerous examples) to check the species against this other layer. Generally the performance is better if you save the result in your data using Field Calculator, rather than run it on the fly as a label filter.

Comment: Separately, if you want to use case insensitive matches, just convert the species field to lowercase before doing the match (with all match constraints also in lowercase). e.g. `regexp_match(lower("species_name", ...` This is a bit harder to use with `attribute(get_feature(...` so you could use `aggregate()` as an alternative. Do you have a separate list to get the data from? If you can share the simplified data structure then it won't be hard to assist with an answer.

Comment: This is more of a database design question. Normally you'd put your species into a species table where you can add fields like "sensitive". Then you'd put your observations into a separate table using the species table as an id/lookup/control. That means you're managing the "sensitive" flag once, and also making sure that the data are identical for any given species.